# Prove (or disprove) that limit is preserved under Gram-Schmidt process

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, gram-schmidt

I am trying to prove or disprove the following statement:

For a general inner product space $(V, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$, if a sequence $(\vec{w}_n)_n$ in $V$ is such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\vec{w}_{n+1}-\vec{w}_n) = \vec{w}_1$, then the orthonormal set $({\vec{v}_n})_n$ obtained from $(\vec{w}_n)_n$ through the Gram-Schmidt process also satisfy the property that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\vec{v}_{n+1}-\vec{v}_n) = \vec{v}_1$.

What I have attempted so far:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} (\vec{v}_{n+1}-\vec{v}_n) 
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}(\vec{w}_{n+1}-\sum_{j=1}^n\langle\vec{v}_j, \vec{w}_{n+1}\rangle\vec{v}_j - \vec{w}_n + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\langle\vec{v}_j, \vec{w}_{n}\rangle\vec{v}_j)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}(\vec{w}_{n+1}-\vec{w}_n) - \lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{j=1}^n\langle\vec{v}_j, \vec{w}_{n+1}\rangle\vec{v}_j - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\langle\vec{v}_j, \vec{w}_{n}\rangle\vec{v}_j)\\
&= \vec{w}_1 - \lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{j=1}^n \langle\vec{v}_j, \vec{w}_{n+1}-\vec{w}_n\rangle\vec{v}_j + \langle\vec{v}_n,\vec{w}_n\rangle\vec{v}_n)
\end{align*}
I'm not sure where to go from here...

Comment: The conclusion is not true . If $u_n$ is an orthonormal system then $\langle u_{n+1}-u_n,u_1\rangle =0$ for $n>1.$ In general  the sequence $u_{n+1}-u_n$ is not convergent, as $\langle u_{n+1}-u_n,v\rangle \to 0$ and $\langle u_{n+1}-u_n, u_{n+1}-u_n\rangle=2.$

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RyszardSzwarc! Could you please explain the last line of your reasoning? Specifically, what is $\langle u_{n+1} - u_n,v\rangle \rightarrow 0$ referring to?

Comment: If  $u_n$ is an orthonormal system then $\langle u_n,v\rangle \to 0 .$ This follows for example from the Bessel inequality $$\sum |\langle u_n,v\rangle |^2\le \|v\|^2$$